# Decomposition into product of prime ideals

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\Bbb{Q}(a)$, where $a$ satisfies $a^3 - 5a + 5 = 0$.
For $n\le7$, I need to compute explicitly the decomposition of $n\Bbb{Z}_K$ as a product of prime ideals. Here $\Bbb{Z}_k$ stands for the ring of integers of $K$. What's the easiest way say to compute these?

Comment: Do you happen to know, if $a$ gives an integral basis? That is, whether $\mathcal{O}_K=\Bbb{Z}[a]$?

Comment: Yes it does, I figured that out. So Z[a] is indeed the ring of integers.

Comment: Z_K is the ring of integers and I'm multiplying by natural number n to yield nZ_K. It would be great if you could TeX this question for me. Many Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Good! Then you can use the theorem (due to Dedekind IIRC) that if modulo a prime $p$ you have the factorization
$$
x^3-5x+5\equiv\prod_i p_i(x)^{a_i}\pmod p
$$ where $p_i(x)$ are irreducible modulo $p$, then you get the factorization
$$p\mathcal{O}_k=\prod_i \langle p, p_i(a)\rangle^{a_i}.$$ Furthermore, those ideals $\langle p, p_i(a)\rangle$ are prime.

Comment: This polynomial isn't mod 5 is it?

Comment: Modulo $p=5$ you get
$$x^3-5x+5\equiv x^3.$$ So the theorem says that 
$$5\mathcal{O}_K=\mathfrak{p}^3,$$
where $\mathfrak{p}$ is the ideal generated by both $5$ and $a$.

Comment: Makes sense. I get that this polynomial is irreducible mod 2 . Can you confirm this?

Comment: Modulo $2$ it is irreducible all right.

Comment: So 2O_K is the prime factorisation? Is O_K the prime factorisation for mod 1, since this polynomial is irreducible over Q?

Comment: Yes. $2$ is inert, so $2\mathcal{O}_K$ is a prime ideal. I didn't understand what you mean by factorization modulo $1$.

Comment: By modulo 1 I meant the n=1 case. So nO_K = O_K. Is the prime factorisation of this just itself?